# Why log4javascript.trace method does not work?

Tags: javascript, logging, log4javascript

From documentation I can see that there is such function but it does not work. Why?
http://log4javascript.org/docs/quickstart.html

I saw one bug about it, but it was marked as fixed, so I got latest version but bug is still in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `trace()` method does work but is disabled by default.

Each logger has a level, which defaults to `DEBUG`. You can change this using its `setLevel()` method:

```
var log = log4javascript.getDefaultLogger();
log.setLevel(log4javascript.Level.TRACE);
```

This will be enough to enable tracing for the default logger, as used in the quick start guide.

There is also a threshold logging level for each appender which can be set via the appender's `setThreshold()` level. What this level defaults to depends on the appender, but for most appenders the level is `ALL`, meaning all logging messages sent to the appender are logged.